# How can I remove images that are loading too slow using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I allow users to submit images to use as thumbnails on my website. The thumbnails aren't stored on my servers. Sometimes, a few of them are really slow. How can I remove the ones that are taking too long to load? The only thing that I can think of is using .load() or .error(), but those events won't even fire until the images load/fail.

Edit: or even better, how can I temporarily display a loading .gif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using animated gif as a background of thumbnail containing div?

Answer (score 1):

You could always code the images (the tags in the page, that is) to use some sort of "loading" image, which, being the same all the time, is likely to be cached.  Then you can load the real images into Image objects. When the "load" event fires for those, you can re-assign the "src" attribute of the tags so that the now-loaded image is shown.

```
<!-- in the page -->
<img class='slow' src='common_loading_image.png' data-real-image='the/real/image.png'>

// JS code
$(function() {
  $('img.slow').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this), real = new Image();

    real.onload = function() {
      $img.src = real.src;
    };
    real.src = $img.data('realImage');
  });
});
```

This relies of course on your images being served with headers appropriate for caching.  If the images aren't being cached, then you'll have to try something like the background image suggestion.

Comment: The whole point is to get the images into the cache so that subsequently updating the "src" attribute of an `<img>` tag will not result in another HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a loading floater above the actual image, and when load(), hide the loading floater

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution if to use a background load image as Pointy and Mati wrote.

However if you really want to remove them, you could handle the load event on all images to mark the downloaded images.

Using a timer you can check after x seconds which images have not been loaded and delete them.